# Database table shows record but value is null on retrieval

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Trying to assign a user to a ticket item, the Ticket table shows a userID for the ticket but on retrieval the owningUser field of the Ticket Model appears null.

***What I'm trying to achieve:***

The user types in the username of the user they wish to assign the ticket to during the ticket creation process. The user is found and assigned to the ticket and the ticket is saved to the database.

### Model

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public bool isDone { get; set; }

    public User owningUser { get; set; }

    public TicketType ticketType { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller: Find user -> Assign user to ticket -> Save ticket

```
 try
        {
            // Find user
            userValid = _userManager.Users.Where(s => s.Email == ticket.owningUser.Username).First();
            var ID = _userManager.Users.First(c => c.Email.Contains(userValid.Email)).Id;

            ticket.owningUser = new User
            {
                UserId = Guid.Parse(ID),
                Username = userValid.Email
            };

            _context.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetTicket", new { id = ticket.Id }, ticket);

        } catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

This is how I am retrieving the user from UserController

### User Controller to retrieve user associated to ticket

```
[HttpGet("{ticketID}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUserForTicket(Guid ticketID)
    {
        var ticketUser = await context.Tickets.FindAsync(ticketID);

        if (ticketUser.owningUser != null)
            return new User { UserId = ticketUser.owningUser.UserId, Username = ticketUser.owningUser.Username };
        else
            return BadRequest("no owning user");
    }
```

### Ticket table shows a owningUserUserID

[image]

### When trying to retrieve the user using the ticket

[image]

### From migration

```
            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Tickets_Users_owningUserUserId",
            table: "Tickets",
            column: "owningUserUserId",
            principalTable: "Users",
            principalColumn: "UserId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

### Tried suggestions [Using Include]

```
 var ticketUser = context.Tickets.Include( o => o.owningUser).First(p => p.Id == ticketID);

if (ticketUser.owningUser != null)
            return new User { UserId = ticketUser.owningUser.UserId, Username = ticketUser.owningUser.Username };
        else
            return BadRequest("no owning user");
```

The server responded with 400 which is bad request, it remains null.

Comment: `Ticket.owningUser` doesn't seem to have a `[ForeignKey]` attribute on it. Do you have a Fluent `.HasForeignKey(...)` definition for it in your `OnModelCreating(...)` method?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the post and added the migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey() method from the migration where a foreign key is added. Do I need to further specify [ForeignKey] on the atrribute? Also in my dbContext class I do not have a OnMondelCreating() method, not sure how to use this or it's purpose. Very new to blazor and EF